# Place admob to the bottom in webview

Tags: android, webview

I have the following layout but admob is shown at the top. How do I position admob to the bottom?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/webview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
android:id="@+id/adView"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id"/>

</WebView>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap it in a Relative Layout, and set `android:layout_alignParentBottom` on the AdView eg:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_unit_id" ads:adSize="BANNER" />

    <WebView android:id="@+id/webView" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </WebView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I read somewhere `android:layout_alignParentBottom` is deprecated, is that true?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a LinearLayout vertical orientation, then you can locate first the webview, the webview put a weight of 4 (this will be the portion that occupies on the screen according to the sum of all weights of the other elements in this case are 6 Weight, the screen divided into 6 pieces and for use webview 4 or whatever you want) and second you use admob with a weight of 2.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="4"
        android:id="@+id/webView" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/admob_unit_id" ads:adSize="BANNER" />

</LinearLayout>
```